# To remove Chinese characters as features -

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-extraction

I have created document-term matrix using TfIdfVectorizer, but just noticed the feature contains Chinese characters. Is it possible to remove them using Python's regex?

I believe these characters are one of reason for lower prediction accuracy of my model.

Currently I use the below for pre-processing my data-

```
   # Pre-processing the data
    def text_preprocess( data ):
        # Changing to lower case
        data = data.lower()
        # Removing special characters
        data = re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",data)
        return data
```

Also, please note I used `stopwords='english'` in my `TfidfVectorizer`.

Please let me know if any information required. (New here, still learning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove non-English characters then this regex will work, by selecting characters not in a given ASCII range (0 to 122, you can adjust this since it will allow some special characters):

```
([^\x00-\x7A])+
```

So to remove those characters:

```
data = re.sub("([^\x00-\x7F])+"," ",data)
```

Comment: Perfect. Even I was thinking on same line, like excluding all non-keyboard characters. But then realised, someone might have Chinese characters on their keyboards. :) You rightly pointed at the ASCII codes. Thanks.